# Use fields from users table in all databases

Tags: mysql, sql

We've got 1 main (MySQL) database (`main`) that holds general information including a table for the users with some information.

And next to that we've got 1 database for each company (`main_1`, `main_2`, ...), also with a table for the (duplicate) users.
The 2nd tier users table has information that the 1st tier doesn't have.

So we need to filter the users from the tier 1 database with values from tier 2 databases.

I know we can get a list of the databases using:

```
SELECT *
FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA
WHERE schema_name LIKE "main_%"
```

But then we would need to union the user tables from all the databases.

If anyone has an idea, much obliged.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Sample data would help us out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to build a statement for presentation to dynamic sql for example

```
set @sql = 
(select  group_concat('select * from ', schema_name,'.users union all ') 
from
(
SELECT schema_name FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA
) s
)
;
set @sql = replace(@sql,',', ' ');
set @sql = substring(@sql, 1, length(@sql) - 11);
set @sql = concat(@sql,';');
```

Produces (in my db)

```
select @sql

select * from bank.users union all  
select * from classicmodels.users union all  
select * from information_schema.users union all  
select * from mysql.users union all  
select * from performance_schema.users union all  
select * from sandbox.users union all  
select * from test.users;
```

Which you then submit

```
prepare sqlstmt from @sql;
execute sqlstmt;
deallocate prepare sqlstmt;
```